# Не получается сравнить типы данных

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a= 210
b= ((a/7)-27)/3
if b is int():
    print(b)
else:
    print('Error')
```

Как сделать так чтоб выводило целое число, а если получается с плавающей точкой: выводило сообщение об ошибке?

Comment: Извините если плохо объяснил ситуацию. У меня вообще нет опыта в постановке вопросов.

Comment: Лучше не пытаться проверять равенство `int` и `float`, а проверять делимость `int` с помощью операции взятия остатка от деления (`%`).

Answer (score 4):

```
a = 210
b = ((a / 7) - 27) / 3
if b.is_integer():
    print(int(b))
else:
    print('Error')
```

Comment: Мистер, вы мой спаситель, спасибо большое.

Comment: @Росомахич, лучшее спасибо - принятый ответ )))